# Can not read doc file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here, I have uploaded doc and docx file in codeigniter. Now, I want to get content of doc file. So I have write code like :

```
$url = base_url().'uploads/resume/Nisarg.doc';
$fp = fopen($url, 'r');
$meta_data = stream_get_contents($fp);

print_r($meta_data);
```

Now, when I print content then it return data in different way that looks like this :

```
PKToH^Æ2''mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.textPKToH«V¹÷Thumbnails/thumbnail.png‰PNG  IHDRÆßƒùr÷PLTE$#*(-8>%*?,5.9I8:B08UqøÄ¨6¼râ•W^}õ•“'NÄ«cöìÁýµ´ÿîõ+¿µfÛ¾}û†‡‡†ÿ©ÊrãÍýûöï?84´ôó7ÝtÓ>ÿg÷ï<]epHË€}CKoÒÓŸÜtÓ7‡†‡ß¬2ŒWÇýóÿî»³qãÆ¿ú“›¶iEªúrCÃÐÒÓ¿ËÆÍ?~êÇ›o¹é'Cz¡ªºÜ°9†ößÿî†ÍO=õÔßÿ×/è™ñ\µa¼2¤gÇî/þõ-ßÝ°á–¿ÙðWƒ:†ýÿTÆ »–CÏþõÆM7nÚôØæ ?Ó1vW%†}÷÷6lÞô˜^ªþþ9û }p°Ú0ÚƒZåô›tŒÿð9»ñlõa8v;v»ý¾·ióæ§{
```

But, I want exact words that are in doc file. So how can resolve this?

**Note :** Here I have copied some data of content.

Comment: You need to send the correct headers to tell the browser that it is a doc file

Comment: @MarkBaker how can i send header? I dont know atchually because I am trying first time.

Comment: In PHP you use the [header()](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) statement, and then stop CI sending its own headers

Comment: you cant simply open a doc file and expect it spits out the words you need - just try tu use a library like https://phpword.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

    $url = base_url().'uploads/resume/Nisarg.doc';
    $word = new COM("word.application") or die ("Could not initialise MS Word object.");
    $word->Documents->Open(realpath($url));

    $content = (string) $word->ActiveDocument->Content;

    echo nl2br($content);

    /*  If need add
        $word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);
        $word->Quit();
        $word = null;
        unset($word);*/
?>
```

Comment: Its display nothing.